# how to pip install globally on ubuntu

Tags: package-management, python

Is there a way to create an globally environment or allow pip installation globaly

the sofware im trying to install is failing and and i think is trying to pip install somthing

```
modular install mojo
# Found release for https://packages.modular.com/mojo @ 0.2.1, installing to /home/christopher/.modular/pkg/packages.modular.com_mojo
# Downloads complete, setting configs...
# Configs complete, running post-install hooks...
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.
    
    See /usr/share/doc/python3.11/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.
modular: error: failed to run python:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. Instead, see what it says in the error:

```
If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
sure you have python3-full installed.
```

Do that instead (or `source path/to/venv/bin/activate` to have `python` and `pip` point to those venv commands).

Trying to install Python packages using `pip` system-wide is a shortcut to screwing up your system. Just don't.